# What is the UUID version generated by JDK 11?

Tags: uuid, java-11

I am using JDK 11.0.2. What is the default UUID version if i do:

```
UUID.randomUUID();
```

Adding more details. By version i mean UUID v1 / UUID v2 / v3 / v4 etc..

Comment: What do you mean with “*default* UUID version”? There is only one version number corresponding to “random”, [as documented](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/UUID.html#version()). It’s also mentioned in [the documentation of `randomUUID()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID()) itself, though it inconsistently calls it “type” rather than “version”.

Comment: The documentation provided by you points to Java 17. I was referring Java 11.

Comment: The UUID standard goes back to long before that.  A random UUID is type 4.  End of story.  Not that it would matter in any circumstance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to comments above, i also tried the `version()` method to get the uuid version.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/UUID.html#version()